# Error que te permite crear una cuenta de gmail sin codigo de verificacion

Tags: seguridad

Inicié el proceso de creación de cuentas de gmail para empresa y en el paso de verificación telefónica (cuando te obligan a colocar el teléfono para verificar tu cuenta si o si) puedes colocar un numero de teléfono , uno que ya tenga una cuenta asociada a la cual te envían un código(en mi caso use el mismo que tenia en mi cuenta anterior) sin embargo en lugar de aceptar y seguir con el proceso, regrese para cambiar la contraseña y se me habilito la opción de "ahora no" para ingresar el numero luego , pero no escribí en ningún lugar el código recibido en mi teléfono, es mas, no es android, es un celular que no tiene internet...
como google permite esto? 
no puede alguien crearse otra cuenta de correo y tener un face/instragram, etc... y crearse cuanta cuenta falsa quiera?
ese filtro no sirve?

Answer (score 0):

No se puede, tal vez te ha dejado de momento pero al verificar los datos nuevamente (porque lo hará) ahí sera donde tengas un problema. Puedes omitir el # pero siempre te lo estará recordando al inicio de una sesión porque google lo toma como una medida mas de seguridad. Así que si de momento no apareció, lo hará.

Comment: hola vic, . ya lo confirme, en la tercera no lo pude hacer, supongo que no se cargo algo bien en mi pc. Saludos